# Changing diff color visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm pretty noob when it comes to Visual studio.  I am using 2012.  I just downloaded the theme editor and got the son of obsidian dark background theme.  When I do a diff, I get a very ugly green background for additions with white text.  It's very hard to read.  How do I change this?  I tried looking in the XML, but I couldn't figure out what was what.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To update the colors used in the diff tool, navigate to TOOLS>OPTIONS>Environment>Fonts and Colors. Choose Text Editor in the Show settings for: drop down. In the Display items: list you will find multiple Diff settings (ie. Added, Differences). Select the setting you want to modify and adjust the colors accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this - one thing is that the foreground colours set for Diff generally get overridden by other styling for the highlighted text, which is why obsidian with its light text is a nightmare for Diff - Added colors